# some question about the identity of curl and divergence

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Say a vector field $F$ where its curl is non zero and there are scalar field $\phi,\mu$ s.t $\mu F=\nabla\phi$, then $\nabla\times F$ is perpendicular to $F$

Attempts: if  $\nabla\times F\cdot F=0$ then they are perpendicular. but it seems this is quite trivial as from the identity $\nabla\cdot(F\times G)=(\nabla\times F)\cdot G-F\cdot(\nabla\times G)$. But it doesn't involves the $2^{nd}$condition. Is it alright just apply the identity without the second condition???

Comment: Try taking the curl on both sides of $\mu F=\nabla\phi$. Then isolate $\nabla\times F$.

Comment: I think you need to spell out how you intend to use that identity. Substituting $F$ for $G$ just yields $0=0$, with no implication for $(\nabla\times F)\cdot F$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mu \mathbf F = \boldsymbol \nabla \phi$, so taking the curl on both sides (as suggested in the comments), \begin{align*}
\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \times(\mu \mathbf F) &= \boldsymbol \nabla \times (\boldsymbol \nabla \phi) \\
\boldsymbol \nabla \mu \boldsymbol \times \mathbf F + \mu \boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \times \mathbf F &= \mathbf 0 \\
\boldsymbol \nabla\boldsymbol \times \mathbf F &= -\frac{1}{\mu} \boldsymbol \nabla \mu \boldsymbol \times \mathbf F,
\end{align*}
where $\mu \ne 0$. Thus $\boldsymbol \nabla \times \mathbf F$ is parallel to $\boldsymbol \nabla \mu \boldsymbol \times \mathbf F$, which is perpendicular to $\mathbf F$.

So $\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \times \mathbf F$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf F$, as required.